# how to use click event in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My code:

```
<%@categories.each_with_index do |d,index| %>

  <%= link_to d.name ,{:action=>'index',:id=>d.id,:hotel_id=>d.hotel_id},class: "btn-orange" %>

<%end%>
```

In my Controller:

```
def index   

    @category = Category.where(:hotel_id => params[:hotel_id]).first

    @menus2=Menu.where(:category_id=> @category.id).sorted

    @categories=Category.where(:hotel_id=>params[:hotel_id])

    @cart = current_cart
    if params[:name]==params[:name]

      @menus=Menu.where(:category_id=> params[:id]).sorted 
    else
    end
end
```

I am new in rails.I want to use `@menus2=Menu.where(:category_id=> 0).sorted` this code when link_to is clicked.How can i do in my controller, is there any click event in ROR.

Comment: can you post your controller's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a remote attribute to your link_to method:

```
= link_to d.name, controller_index_path, class: 'btn etc', remote: true
```

This will allow Rails to make an 'Ajax' call to your desired controller.

**Note**: when making a remote call such as this, Rails will receive/respond via .js. This means that you need to have an index.js.erb file that does what you need and reports back to the 'Ajax' caller whatever data is necessary.

This page in the Rails guide may help with additional details, etc.: [Working with JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)